# How to place all showDialog elements centered in the flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm having trouble creating showDialog. I want to draw a dialog apo sample I have all the elements. But the problem is that I can't place them properly. Here's what I want to do:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P5ZUm.jpg)

I'm having trouble creating showDialog. I want to draw a dialog apo sample I have all the elements. But the problem is that I can't place them properly. Here's what I want to do:

There is text, an icon and a button. I created it all, but there is a problem with the display, it's not in the center. Here is my code, can anyone know how all this will lead to a normal look, I will be grateful.

```html
_showDialog(BuildContext context) {
  showDialog(
    context: context,
    builder: (BuildContext ctx) {

      // return object of type Dialog
      return AlertDialog(
          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(15)),
          ),
        title: Center(child: Text(Titles.serviceNotAvailable)),
        //content: const Text(Titles.serviceNotAvailable),
        actions: <Widget>[

          SvgPicture.asset(Img.simpleOrder),
          CustomElevatedButton(
            isDark: false,
            isEnabled: false,
            onPressed: () {
              _showDialog(context);
            },
            child: Text(
              Titles.backToChoiceServices,
              style: TextStyle(
                color: Colorz.primary,
                fontSize: FontSize.small,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
              ),
            ),

          ),
        ],
      );
    },
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Trye to wrap it in a Center widget, setting it as his child.